# How can I change property value with Sinon in unit test?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, sinon, qunit

I have this code:

```
AlertHelper = function () {
    return {
        DisplayToastMessage: function() {
            if ($("body > .modal.small").length > 1) {
                AlertHelper.CalculateAdditionalHeight();
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

And I tried to write unit tests with QUnit and SinonJS.

This is the unit test:

```
QUnit.test('DisplayToastMessage - testing function call', function (assert) {
    var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    var mock = sinon.mock(AlertHelper);

    sandbox.stub($("body > .modal.small"), "length", 42);

    var expectationCalculateAdditionalHeight = mock.expects("CalculateAdditionalHeight");
    expectationCalculateAdditionalHeight.once();

    AlertHelper.DisplayToastMessage();

    mock.verify();
    assert.ok(mock.verify(), "CalculateAdditionalHeight function is called once");

    sandbox.restore();
    mock.restore();
});
```

but I receive an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".
How can I test that CalculateAdditionalHeight function is called?

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking the instance:

`$ = sinon.stub();
$.withArgs('body > .modal.small').returns({"length": 42});`

Comment: I guess that I need to add in the end $.restore(); Am I right?

Comment: It works, but I need to restore value. Do you know how to restore stub?

Comment: Yes, you can restore using $.restore(); Refer the document at http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.2/stubs/. Also, you can use beforeEach/before to set your expectations for each test case.

Comment: I added $.restore();. There is an error "$.restore is not a function". Do you know why?

Comment: I found that after overwriting `$`, there is no way to restore it, because reference is not created.

Answer (score 0):

After researching I found solution:

```
QUnit.test('DisplayToastMessage - testing function call', function (assert) {
    var mock = sinon.mock(AlertHelper);
    var fake$ = sinon.stub(window, '$');

    fake$.withArgs('body > .modal.small').returns({ "length": 42 });

    var expectationCalculateAdditionalHeight = mock.expects("CalculateAdditionalHeight");
    expectationCalculateAdditionalHeight.once();

    AlertHelper.DisplayToastMessage();

    mock.verify();
    assert.ok(mock.verify(), "CalculateAdditionalHeight function is called once");

    fake$.restore();
    mock.restore();
});
```